# Update hyperlinks in Excel 2010 after copying files

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I recently upgraded an end users' laptop to one that now has Windows 7.  I copied all of his data to a backup drive and restored it into his new My Documents folder.

However, within the spreadsheets, he has local hyperlinks that pointed to a folder on his computer.  So rather than point from `Documents and Settings/jsmith/my docs/foobar/myfile1.pdf`, it is going to a obscure directory.

He has far too many of these files to manually update them.  Is there a macro or an easier way to update all the links? The pattern I think shouldn't be an issue, but we have really no idea how to fix this easily

- The Macro in [How to find and replace link paths in multiple Excel files at once](https://superuser.com/questions/81283/how-to-find-and-replace-link-paths-in-multiple-excel-files-at-once) did not work. These are local files, not websites.  They are pointing to PDFs as mentioned above.
- The HTML conversion is causing issues too.
- If you go to edit hyperlink manually, it shows up as:

  ```
  ..\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\foobar\foo%20bar\AA11111%20Foo%20Bar.pdf
  ```

  Why?
- PowerGREP also did not work.

Comment: Similar to this, too: [How can hyperlinks be programmatically changed in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/573695/how-can-hyperlinks-be-programmatically-changed-in-excel/573737#573737)

Comment: PowerGrep seems intriguing.  If it makes any difference, if it was just a single file (with multiple workbook-sheets) is there a more a robust search replace?

Comment: This might look similar but it is different because these are local files on the file system.  It is issues from a spreadsheet from Windows XP to Windows 7.  The macro did not work.  Marking it as duplicate was premature and wrong.  Please undo that.

Comment: Jonathan, please don't take this too personally. Nobody's being premature – and now we know the solutions from the other question didn't work, so we can reopen it. Questions are closed and reopened all the time, and if you edit one that's closed, it'll automatically be put in a review queue. No need to flag, really.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't know that, but I did edit that yesterday and wasn't sure what to do as I still got an enduser needing a solution...

Comment: I am not sure exactly what to do because I really need my enduser up and running with this.  Doing it manually will take far too long- he says the Macro doesn't work.  I think because of the temp file space/users directory isn't linking properly.  I am not sure how he created the links initially, but it was originally created in Excel 2003 on Windows XP.  He now uses Windows 7 with Office 2010.